# Intellisense in Visual Studio 2017 is hiding members from the autocomplete list

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and I have run into a problem that I am sincerely hoping is just because I have not found the correct setting. In Visual Studio 2017 I am missing members from my Intellisense list as seen in the comparison pictures below between VS2017 and VS2015.

[image: VS2017 DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection]

[image: VS2015 DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection]

From the two images you can see that VS2017 is not showing the `Count` property whereas VS2015 is. VS2017 is also not showing `IsReadOnly`, `IsSyncronized`, `SyncRoot` if I scroll down it's list.

There must be something I am doing wrong, but I can't seem to get these members to show.

Here is another example comparing `DataGridViewRow` members:

[image: VS2017 vs VS2015 DataGridViewRow]

In this image you can see VS2017 is missing `AdjustRowHeaderBorderStyle`, `DataBoundItem`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you. In VS 2017, Intellisense shows me all the items that you show in the VS 2015 screenshots. Using "Peek definition", I did notice that `Count`, `IsReadOnly`, `IsSyncronized` and `SyncRoot` are all defined in `BaseCollection` while the others are not. Perhaps that provides a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your description, I have reproduced this issue and reported this issue to the VS Product Team, please check this: [VB-Windows Forms: the list members of 'DataGridView.SelectedRows.' miss some members](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/384441/vb-windows-forms-the-list-members-of-datagridviews.html), please add a comment and waiting for the feedback from the Product Team engineers.

Meanwhile, I found we can still use those missing members like ‘Count’ and there is no error reminder.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not limited to just `DataGridView.SelectedRows`, it also occurs on the `DataGridViewRow` and I'm sure many other areas.